# AngularJS orderBy filter not working for data populated by service

Tags: angularjs, service, filter, controller, angularjs-orderby

I am new to AngularJS. I am attempting to filter a list of `recipe` objects provided to the scope by a `recipeService`. My objects appear, but no filter is applied.

If I attach the items directly to the `$scope` to a variable called `recipes` in my `controller.js`, and instead use `ng-repeat="recipe in recipes"`, the filter works.

Any advice? Regards.

HTML

`<li ng-repeat="recipe in recipeService.allRecipes | orderBy:'name':reverse">{{recipe.name}}</li>`

reciperService.service.js in my factory:

```
var service = {};

service.allRecipes = [];

service.getAllRecipes = function () {
  return $http.get('/api/recipes')
    .success(function (recipes) {
      service.allRecipes = recipes;
      return recipes;
    });
};
return service;
```

controller.js in the controller declaration:

```
$scope.recipeService = recipeService;
recipeService.getAllRecipes();
```

Comment: $scope.recipes = recipeService.getAllRecipes();    You should do it this way, sounds like you are aware that this works. It is also the better way to do it.

Comment: Provide js fiddle please!

Comment: Where is the filter?

Comment: orderby is an angular filter. And you said you did it the way i described, shouldn't need a fiddle, right?

Comment: @ribsies I did try that. I should have said that in the op. If i try that, nothing gets populated on the HTML. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick plunker that shows this working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QQmLpmOxUK7rl95hBdIn?p=preview

There might be an issue with using promises the way you are. Maybe, I can't remember. If there is a problem with it you could do a few different things. Either use

```
$q.defer()
```

or

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('something');
```

to update the variable

**Edit**

Not that you are using promises incorrectly, just sometimes since there is a delay with setting the variable and it misses the digest cycle.

**Edit 2**

Or, you could make the function the promise and handle the promise in the controller, that will set the variable properly. That is how I usually do things that involve $http requests. So the service would be...

```
service.getAllRecipts = function() {
  return $http.get(url);
}
```

Then handle the promise in your controller

```
var req = recipeService.getAllRecipes();

req.success(function(data) {
  $scope.recipes = data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your plunker suggestions in my app and I received the promises with the correct data, though nothing was displayed on my HTML. I will look in to this when I get more time this weekend, but I believe the solution is in your reply.

Comment: I would recommend the solution in the Edit 2, that will definitely work and update your scope variable.

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue. @ribsies, I tried your alternatives and they achieved the same results I had in the op. Recipes were posted to html, but the filter still did not work. I discovered the problem was that instead of `orderBy:'name':reverse"`, I needed the expression to be `orderBy:'-name'"`. This filters it in reverse for me. Not sure exactly why this works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue. I tried the alternatives offered by @ribsies and they achieved the same results I had in the op. Recipes were posted to html, but the filter still did not work.

I discovered the problem was that instead of `orderBy:'name':reverse"`, I needed the expression to be `orderBy:'-name'"`. This filters it in reverse for me. Not sure exactly why this works, but it does.

Comment: Oh duh. I didn't even look at that. The third parameter for that is a boolean. So it's true or false, but either way works fine. Glad you got it figured out

Comment: Ah yes. I can't believe I missed the 3rd parameter is a boolean. I must have misunderstood the docs..  Thanks @ribsies!